# What is the correct way to interpret the sentence "You can't have too many"?

Tags: meaning

> It's like chef's in a kitchen for that part of a game's engine. You can't
>   have too many.
>   - Quoted from a conversation with a friend.

When said in this context, my friend interpreted as "You can always have more chefs."

When I said it, I meant "You can't realistically have many more chefs."

Given only this context, what is the correct way to interpret the sentence as written? We're both arguing semantics over this now, and it would be nice for a third party to just settle this so we can move on.

This is my first time on this StackExchange, so I have no idea which tags to use or if this is even the proper question etiquette here. My apologies.

Comment: What you *meant* to say was, "You can't have too many *more*."

Answer (score 0):

In my view, there are some mixed metaphors involved in your discussion. A more common aphorism relating to chefs--"Too many chefs spoils the soup."--means you *can* have too many. The aphorisms I have most closely heard relating to "You cant have too many / much..." involve things like money, success, happiness, beauty, &c.

As far as how to interpret the quote from your conversation, My rule of thumb is that the speaker who spoke the phrase gets to define what it means. Even if the speaker's definition resembles a mixed metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct way to articulate your meaning would have been to say "You shouldn't have too many". "You can't have too many" is a figure of speech which is usually interpreted the way that your friend did.

I use that phrase when I am referring to discrete and desirable things like books, cookies, etc. - basically, there is no such thing as too many cookies so 'can't have too many cookies'.